# @Override error after adding public interface OnTaskCompleted

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to get a response back from my public class saveData extends AsyncTask.
I added a public interface but the Android Studio gives me an error for the `@Overide` on my `onCreate` in the activity.

```
public class almostFinish extends Activity implements OnTaskCompleted{

    @Override // here I get an Error
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(boolean result) {
    //ToDo
    }
}
```

My interface.

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
    void onTaskCompleted(boolean isSuccess);
}
```

My AsyncTask class

```
public class saveData extends AsyncTask<List<String>, Void, Void> {
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    boolean myflag = false;

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<String>... params) { }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);        
        listener.onTaskCompleted(myflag);       
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

I'm just getting an Error in the editor: "Annotations are not allowed here"
If I remove the @Override then I get an Error telling me to add @Override.

Comment: What error is it showing? *Always* specify the exact error, rather than just saying "an error".

Comment: He has mentioned in comment saying // here I get an Error on @Override.

Comment: @KarthikR: That says *where* there's an error - it doesn't show *what* the error is. (I suspect that if the OP had included the error, it would have made it obvious it had nothing to do with accessibility, for example...)

Comment: Maybe I is just warning that you have forgot to call super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)? But I would be more helpful, if we know the error message.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yeah. As you mentioned, I overlooked that as an interface' @ Override. Removed answer as well.

Comment: Please say whats the error you get and also post your Activity.java code ehre

Comment: A line with public sip.listener had been added that is why I got the "Annotations are not allowed here"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. According this code you will get null pointer exception. because you have not assign the listener in code.

   ```
   public class saveData extends AsyncTask < List < String > , Void, Void > {
       private OnTaskCompleted listener;
       boolean myflag = false;

       @Override
       public void onPreExecute() {}

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(List < String > ...params) {}

       @Override
       public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           onTaskCompleted(myflag);
       }
   }
   ```